# Inserting NULL integer using VB.Net and EF5

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

Working on an application that relies on an older version of entity, and I'm trying to insert a `NULL` into an `int` field. The field in SQL Server is `(int, null)`.

Here's the definition of the object in EF:

```
<EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty:=false, IsNullable:=true)>
<DataMemberAttribute()>
Public Property application_id() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
```

...and here is where I'm trying to set it:

```
applications.application_id = IIf(IsNumeric(txtAppID.Text), CInt(txtAppID.Text), Nothing)
```

The error thrown in response is:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ... but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

I can confirm that this issue is being thrown due to the `Nothing` portion because previously it was `applications.application_id = CInt(txtAppID.Text)` and all was fine.

I've tried `DBNull.Value` instead of `Nothing`, though the error reads the same. Done a fair bit of research though most issues relate to ES6 or `datetime` fields, and as such I felt my issue was specific enough to warrant its own question.

Thanks.

Comment: Change the code so you only add a value to the record if it is numeric, i.e.: `If IsNumeric(txtAppID.Text) Then applications.application_id = CInt(txtAppID.Text)`

Comment: @LaughingVergil I should've mentioned this is used for updates as well. Using that method would mean that the use has no way to *remove* an application ID, because if they blank out the field and update, `applications.application_id` will not get set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IIf` function doesn't short circuit, and therefore always evaluates both the true and false parts, so it's not going to work in that situation.  The `If` keyword does short circuit, but you will probably run into issues with the return type and nullable value types (e.g. `Dim x As Integer? = If(False, 1, Nothing)` results in `x = 0` because the `If` is returning `Integer` and not `Integer?`).

So, I would recommend either using a regular `If` statement:

```vb
If IsNumeric(txtAppID.Text) Then
    applications.application_id = CInt(txtAppID.Text)
Else
    applications.application_id = Nothing
End If
```

or you could create a helper function:

```vb
Function NullableCInt(value As String) As Integer?
    If IsNumeric(value) Then Return CInt(value)
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

and use that:

```vb
applications.application_id = NullableCInt(txtAppID.Text)
```

Comment: Appreciate it, what a nasty oversight! I fixed it by simply doing `Dim AppID as Integer? = IIf(IsNumeric(txtAppID.Text), txtAppID.Text, Nothing)` and `applications.application_id = AppID` and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: You may want to turn `Option Strict On`, which wouldn't allow implicit casting like that, but would result in more robust code.

Comment: Correct, I was quick to say my method worked prior to testing all cases. I actually really like Fabio's solution, however yours is no less correct. I appreciate your input and leading me in the right direction here.

Comment: @Santi Yes, especially @Fabio's performance optimization with `TryParse` is nice, so I'm going to borrow that one for my own code! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get working `If` method with casting

```vb
Dim temp As Integer
applications.application_id = If(Integer.TryParse(value, temp), temp, DirectCast(Nothing, Integer?))
```

For better readability you can introduce "default" value

```vb
Static DEFAULT_VALUE As Integer? = Nothing    
Dim temp As Integer
applications.application_id = If(Integer.TryParse(value, temp), temp, DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

With `Integer.TryParse` you need "check/convert" string to integer only once.